# view rendered differently when I split the xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am fairly new to android programming, but not new to java.

I have been trying to setup a non-trivial view, and I'm having an odd problem.  I have designed a layout that horizontally scrolls individual player panels (it's Yet Another ScoreKeeper)

So I created a playermain.xml with the HorizontalScrollView and LinearLayout to contain dynamically added player panels which are a TableLayout.

I want the playerpanel buttons and fields to stretch to consume all available playing space vertically (I also have some goals for horizontal, but let's ignore those for now)

Nothing I tried will get the playing panels to stretch - instead they center, but don't fill.  The strange thing is, I tried a quick test, which was to create a flattened version of the xml files (ie. I copied two copies of the playerpanel xml into the main xml.  when i simply setContentView to this combined xml I get the view I want.

When I do it programatically, I don't get the stretch, and I must be missing something here.  I can also post the combined xml, but I thought it unnecessary, basically when I create a single xml file with Scrolls, Layout and tablelayouts, things stretch the way I want.  When I create the Scroll/Layout with one xml file, then add the other items to the top level LinearLayout, they don't stretch.

onCreate:
<----SNIP----->

```
   setContentView(R.layout.playingmain);
   final LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   LinearLayout llayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);


       TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.playerpanel, null);
       InitializePlayer(player1,tl);
       llayout.addView(tl);
```

<----SNIP----->

MAINPANEL.XML

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"


    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:isScrollContainer="true" 
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Individual Panel.xml:

```
 <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:minWidth="200sp"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/NameRow"  
            android:minWidth="500sp"
            android:layout_weight = "1"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/PlayerName"
                android:text="PlayerName" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dbg1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/scoreRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight = "1"  
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentScore"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="10"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dbg2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="TextView" 
                />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow17"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight = "1"  
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/subtractButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="-"  
            />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/scoreEntry"
                android:layout_span = "2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="+" 
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight = "1"  
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plusOne"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="+1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plusFive"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="+5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/minusOne"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="-1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/minusFive"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="-5" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I add the inflated objects, I needed to specify the proper parent object instead of null.  Once I did that, all xml properties made it into the views.

I was able to confirm/debug this using the hierarchy viewer.

```
  TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.playerpanel, null);
```

needed to be

```
  TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.playerpanel, llayout, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Akameswaran,

The reason for this discrepency is simple: XML are "statically" defined with dynamic results based on those static paramaters. That is, XML provides an initial inflation using initial state defined by those XML files. The code, allows changes to be made at runtime and is treated by the engine as "dynamic" even if the positions and dimensions are constant. This leads to some very interesting relationships for those who are unfamiliar with Android.

When you have one XML file, during inflation the rendering engine knows what all of the objects are and how they relate to the view hierarchy. However, when you split the XML file, it doesn't know that the properties of the child views are dependant upon the properties of the parent views, unless you tell it so in code. This is, in essence, because the computer does exactly what you tell it to and freaks out if you don't tell it enough. It will "guess" but almost always guess incorrectly. Like HTML, Android is made to work as much as possible providing A RESULT if it can, even if it is the wrong one.

Android provides several ways to overcome this: OnLayout() allows you to dynamically apply positioning to any activity or view object. OnMeasure() allows you to redefine dimensions. OnDraw() allows you to dynamically draw or inflate the object. By overriding these functions, you can get the behavior back to what you need and still keep you XML modular, like you so desire. Since you are using standardized API controls, you'll probably want to override the functions directly in the Activity and save yourself a lot of trouble.

Hope this helps,
FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Thanks for the input, however, I tracked down the root cause.  When I was adding the inflated .xml I was not specifying the parent, this caused my "match_parent" properties to not be applied.  This is documented in the UI